# Convert array to string

Tags: python, list

I have a reeeealy huge string, which looks like `['elem1','elem2',(...)]` and contains about 100,000(!) elements.
What is the best method to change it back to a list?

Comment: Um, is it convert to string or convert to array you are looking for?

Comment: Are you sure it is a string and you are not doing something like `repr(yourlist)`? Care to share some code?

Comment: yes, it is string from text file, which was writed by me - eval works well

Answer (score 3):

`eval("['elem1','elem2']")` gives you back list `['elem1','elem2']`

If you had string looking like this `["elem1","elem2",(...)]` you might use `json.read()` (in python 2.5 or earlier) or `json.loads()` (in python 2.6) from `json` module to load it safely.

Comment: Does the JSON parser distinguish between single- and double-quotes?

Comment: It seems so. Trying to json.read("['a']") gives json.ReadException: Input is not valid JSON: '['a']'

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is:

```
input = "['elem1', 'elem2' ] "
result_as_list = [ e.strip()[1:-1] for e in input.strip()[1:-1].split(",") ]
```

This builds the complete result list in memory. You may switch to generator expression

```
result_as_iterator =  ( e.strip()[1:-1] for e in input.strip()[1:-1].split(",") )
```

if memory consumption is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `eval`, this may work:

```
big_string = """['oeu','oeu','nth','nthoueoeu']"""

print big_string[1:-2].split("'")[1::2]
```